# Does Android Studio have a release schedule? (like Chrome)

Tags: android-studio

Does Android Studio have a release schedule? Chrome releases every 6 weeks and I was wondering if Android Studio has something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can build from source any time you want: http://tools.android.com/build#TOC-Building-Android-Studio
- We try to do a build that goes out on the canary channel every week, usually late in the week, but there may be issues that prevent release on any given week. When that happens, we sometimes release it early the next week, and sometimes we punt until the next week's release. It depends on a number of factors.
- During development, if a canary channel build looks good and doesn't cause severe problems for some period of time, we will promote it to dev channel. The idea is that canary channel gets close to the bleeding edge, and dev channel updates are less frequent and more stable.
- We're working up to the full 1.0 release (sorry I'm being vague about the timing, but I'm not announcing a release date here), so the build schedule has been a little topsy-turvy of late. I expect that after 1.0 ships and we get past any post-release maneuvers, we'll fall back to that rhythm.
- In the beta period running up to the release, the beta channel is a bit like the dev channel -- it gets less frequent updates that are better-vetted.